# How to encode & decode non Ascii characters?

Tags: c#, encoding, decoding, non-ascii-characters

I am developing an application in which i want to encode the Spanish text.
But the problem is that,it doesn't encode the special characters such as **á, é, í, ó, ú, ü,Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ü,Ñ,ñ** .
How can i do this?i want  to **encode-decode the spanish text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok,I am answering my own question ,Hope it will help someone; to print spanish or any other non-ascii character in the given string **replace all non-ascii characters by their unicode escape character set 
E.g repalce á by \u00e1**
And then simply print the string.

i.e

```
string str="árgrgrgrááhhttá";
str=str.Replace("á", "\u00e1");
```

Answer (score 4):

For international support using simple `UTF-8` encoding to `encode/decode` your data should be enough.

`Utf-8` has a beautiful capability to be able to read `ASCII`  with one byte, as ordinary ASCII, and Unicode characters with 2 bytes. So it's able "to shrink" when it's necesary.

For complete `C#` documentation look on
[UTF-8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.utf8.aspx)

**EDIT**

```
  Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(true, true);
  string value = " á, é, í, ó, ú, ü,Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ü,Ñ,ñ "; 
  byte[] bytes= enc.GetBytes(value); //convert to BYTE array 

 //save in some file 

 //after can read  from the file like
 string decodedString = enc.GetString(byteArrayReadFromFile);
```

Comment: i tried utf-8 and base64 but it failed to encode non-ascii characters

Comment: I think you don't use it in  a right way. Can provide some code ?

Comment: //encoding using utf-8
 public static string EncodeTo641(string toEncode)

    {
      byte[] toEncodeAsBytes= System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(toEncode);
      string returnValue= System.Convert.ToBase64String(toEncodeAsBytes);
      return returnValue;
  

    }
 
//decoding strings
 public static string DecodeFrom64(string encodedData)
{

    byte[] encodedDataAsBytes= System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodedData);
    string returnValue =System.Text.UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(encodedDataAsBytes);
    return returnValue;

}

Comment: @dd619: you have to use manipulation methods present in that class in order to correctly write/read data in that format. Declaring it's not enough.

Comment: @Tigren: when i pass " á, é, í, ó, ú, ü,Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ü,Ñ,ñ " as encode it gives Ã¡, Ã©, Ã­, Ã³, Ãº, Ã¼,Ã, Ã‰, Ã, Ã“, Ãš, Ãœ,Ã‘,Ã± as output

Comment: @dd619: I see you translete the text to 64bit string, why do you need that?

Comment: i just tried ur code as string decodedString =      enc.GetString(bytes);

Comment: but I don't use 64base conversion, why do you. I translate your string into byte array, fter save it into file, and read it from the file to see that all caharcters are the same I saved before.