# Encoding Accented Characters in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, encoding, diacritics, non-ascii-characters

The user uploads CSV with accented characters like émily, ástha which I need to encode and pass to the backend. I have tried updating the file type in `FormData` between `type: 'text/plain'` and `type: 'text/csv'`.

```
const data = new FormData()
data.append('file', new Blob([params.file], { type: 'text/csv' }))
```

Passed encoding in `FileReader`'s method `readAsText` with params `ISO-8859-1`, `ISO-8859-4`, `ISO-10646-UCS-Basic`, and a couple of other examples from http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets/character-sets.xhtml. Needless to say, tried other unhelpful methods `readAsArrayBuffer` and `readAsBinaryString`.

```
reader.readAsText(file, 'ISO-8859-4')
```

Printing using `ISO-8859-1` gives me `Žmily` and `‡stha` which are not close enough. I need to be able to receive the exact characters (backend uses `ascii folding filter` to convert these into ascii).

I am relying on [How to encode & decode non Ascii characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12576762/how-to-encode-decode-non-ascii-characters) as the last solution.

Any pointers on how can I attempt encoding non ascii characters?

Answer (score 1):

This might be related with the csv encoding [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42462764/javascript-export-csv-encoding-utf-8-issue/42466254). You can prepend the [Byte-Order-Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (BOM) to csv content first, try

```
const BOM = "\uFEFF"; 

new Blob([BOM + params.file], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8' })
```

Comment: Thanks, @anthony. Turns out the file uploaded was not in utf-8 format. It worked after updating the encoding.